# How do I scan for keyboard input to print a predefined text in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a website where a user types any keys in his keyboards, it prints a predefined text.

So for example:

If the predefined text was "Nice to Meet you."

The user would put any 4 keys on his keyboard, and it would type "Nice to meet you."

It would feel like he is typing "Nice to Meet you." while he is just pressing random keys.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am a beginner and just starting to learn html, css, and javascript.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code

Comment: Hi ssongssu, welcome to SO. Around here we can help you with your code when you get stuck and guide you in the right direction. Do you have any code you can share with us where you show us an attempt at creating this? Otherwise we'd just be doing your work, you see. And the worst thing about that is that you don't learn anything. Look into how you can listen for keystrokes and make an attempt. If you get stuck, come back and we'll help you out.

Comment: Ok. I will come back with some code. Thank you for the feed back!